# Remove unwanted characters in a string using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a string like this in my column:

```
<p>[img ret872154ftu] fileaddress [/img ret872154ftu]</p>
<p>[img fd68721cvn] fileaddress [/img fd68721cvn]</p>
<p>[img xdfh654t] fileaddress [/img xdfh654t]</p>
```

Now i wish to remove unwanted chars inside [img] and [/img].
I have already used this query but does not work:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `content` = replace(`content`, '[img [^]*]', '[img]');
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `REPLACE` doesn't take a regular expression, and there is not a native mysql function for regex replacing, only comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET
 column=REPLACE(column,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column,'/img ',-1),']',1),'');

UPDATE table SET
 column=REPLACE(column,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column,'[img ',-1),']',1),'');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c20f9/1)

2 updates,with different delimiters because the texts might be different.